# Armor for mages?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, armor

In 5e whats the ruling about arcane casters wearing armour? Does it impact their spellcasting like in earlier editions? I was looking through the book and didn't see anything but I just wanted to be sure, that if I get proficiency it won't be for nothing.

Comment: Hi Zac. RPG Meta is not for game questions, it's for questions about this site itself, how we work, and the software this site runs on. I've moved this to our main site. What do you mean by "the ruling"? Are you asking whether arcane users can wear armor and how it affects their spellcasting, like it did in previous editions with arcane spell failure?

Comment: Yes, and Sorry I didn't reliaze I had posted it in the wrong section.

Comment: That's ok. Look out for the difference in design - colored versus grey scale & sketchy, as well as the "meta" in the title. It's not an uncommon mistake for new members.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with, [..] you can't cast
>   spells. (PHB 144)

Thus, if you have proficiency with the armor you are wearing, it does not impede your spellcasting (be it arcane or divine).

Comment: Alright, thank you. I thought that was the case but I wanted  second set of eyes because it's so late here.